# The symbols I should be aware of for SQL injection

Tags: php, mysql, shared-hosting

I know that you cure all of the stuff with `mysql_real_escape_string()` (and with `htmlspecialchars()`), but I want to know the symbols that cause all this mess everyone wants to get rid of?

The thing here is, that we here had to transfer a website not built by us from one host to another.

It has been coded from ground up, to utilize `php`'s now deprecated and never loved one - `magic_quotes`.

After the host change there have been `php.ini` changes also, we encountered a lot of unexpected results. We don't have access to `php.ini`, there is no `user.ini` (5.2.x) and the host is is not responsive enough to enable us some extra features. There is a problem with hosting services here in Latvia, a major one.

But yeah, that's off-topic already. I simply want to know, **which symbols** are the ones that **with no escaping**, no magic quotes and no protection can **cause all this mess**?

Plus, there were error when text contained stuff like - `/ls` which resembles UNIX (the host OS) directory listing command - Method Not Implemented.

And it looks like the website interacts with database in CLI environment, hence the `/ls` problem. And I want to confirm that whenever you input a value that starts with `/` and follows UNIX command- "Method Not Implemented" errors comes up.

P.S. I'm *not* looking for a solution, I've already fixed the error. Just want to know the symbols.

### Update to clarify

1) As of writing the question, I was calling `CLI` what looks to be `socket` call- `unix-domain` / `TCP`. Live and learn!

2) If you read the question fully, you'll see that I'm fixing bugs/holes left behind other developers. Sine we took over this clients IT servicing, they wanted us to take over their website too.

3) Because they have paid a lot of money for current website, they don't want to pay even more for a new one on a newer, better built system.

4) The connection line inside the scripts is - `$this->db = DB::connect('mysql://'._DB_USER.':'._DB_PASS.'@'._DB_HOST.'/'._DB_NAME.'');` - `unix-domain` I guess.

Comment: P.S. [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) is NOT used for escaping strings for SQL queries.

Comment: I did not say it is used for escaping. I made a point, that sometimes it helps for protection if, for instance, you use a quote inside titles (`input`, not `textarea`) a lot. Because when you load the value back from DB, it interrupts HTML too, causing unexpected results again. But good point non-the-less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php):

> mysql_real_escape_string() calls MySQL's library function
>   mysql_real_escape_string, which prepends backslashes to the following
>   characters: \x00, \n, \r, \, ', " and \x1a.

Comment: And those 7 symbols are the ones that can interrupt MySQL? I mean.. The question wasn't what symbols `mysql_real_escape_string();` works with, but what symbols can cause SQL errors.

Comment: @Tom: I'm not sure, but since `mysql_real_escape_string` is used to make queries safe I'd assume so.  Unless you weren't quoting your strings in your SQL query or using user data in spots where you shouldn't (like `SELECT $field FROM $table`), because then symbols like (, ), +, and - could mess it up.

Answer (score 2):

Each DB will have its own metacharacters as extensions to standard SQL syntax. Some will use `--` for comments, some use c-style `/* */`, etc... Each DB has its own escaping requirements, which is why there's an escape function for every DB type in PHP. What works for MySQL may be completely useless for (say) Oracle.

The only "definitive" list of characters will be the ones listed in the SQL standards. But using only those in your own custom escape function would be useless, because it won't include the DB-specific non-standard metacharacters that the DB understands.

Comment: I don't want to build a function or anything related to that, just want to know the symbols. Thanks for the insight about different databases!

Comment: And as an additional bit - even if a query is perfectly escaped for your DB in your example, since the query is being passed over as a command line argument, now you've got **2** escaping problems - the sql syntax itself, *AND* the shell's escaping requirements. Now you need to know if it's a Windows or Unix box, because both have completely different shell semantics to consider.

Comment: @MarcB: That's why there's [`escapeshellcmd()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php) or [`escapeshellarg()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php).

Comment: @Rocket: yep. but I wonder why/how the OP is passing queries over a command line. Sounds like he's doing `exec("echo $sql | mysql -p")` or something...**FEAR**