# MySQL CLI web environment halts on /<unix>

Tags: php, mysql

So I just made a [question about symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519717/the-symbols-i-should-be-aware-of-for-sql-injection), but yeah, while the symbols are now working properly, there is still a problem with UNIX commands.

The thing is, whenever I input a value that starts with `/` and follows with a UNIX command, the host responds with - **501 Method Not Implemented.**

What causes this, how to prevent this, and am I right that this happens because of MySQL in CLI environment?

Yes, here in Latvia currency is "Lats", abbreviated to "Ls" and our client tend to seperate values like - "Ls 3 for students, Ls 2 for retirees /Ls 1 for children". And the `/Ls` there screws it all up.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php

However, if you're passing queries to Mysql via a command line, then you're defniitely doing it VERY VERY wrong. The mysql functions in PHP communicate directly with the database via sockets (either unix-domain or TCP). There should NEVER be a shell/command line involved in the process anywhere.

Comment: Not my creation, linked question gives a bit more in-depth look into the situation. But yes, that's what I was looking for. Never had a problem with that, because I'm never using CLI/Sockets for my projects, therefore the question. Thanks!