# Escaping shell / database with utf-8 characters

Tags: php, database, escaping

What is the preferred order for escaping characters?

For instance in `PHP` environment:

1) shell -> database = `return escapeshellcmd(mysqli_real_escape_string($string));`?

2) database -> shell = `return mysqli_real_escape_string(escapeshellcmd($string));`?

3) No difference at all?

### Update

Just to clarify, the website I'm currently trying to fix, contains a lot of old, deprecated functions, uses magic_quotes and is basicly, unusable after the transfer from old host to current one, where the problems arose.

First problem was MySQL escaping, that I fixed with `mysql_real_escape_string();`, but, still the problem with `CLI/Socket` MySQL connection environment persists. That is, when you have a value inside a `textarea` that refers to a UNIX command, preceded by a `/` - forward slash symbol and you post it- Apache results in 501 Method Not Implemented.

So yes, I have to escape `mysql`, and escape `shell` commands. But, the `shell` command escaping (with example no. 1 from original question) resulted in UTF-8 character braking and losing lots of needed HTML symbols.

The content that needs to be escaped comes out of an WYSIWYG editor (SPAW), therefore it contains lot of quotes and from time to time a UNIX command, that resembles our nations - Latvia - currency. "/ls", where LS is the currency.

The website is updated by client itself, not a tech person and it has to stay that way- I mean, we cannot take over the content editing. Plus, while we could tell them not to use `/ls` the UNIX problem persists if, for example, they accidentally get to `/mkdir` what could resemble an identificator of something.

They are an active travel company, therefore this needs to be fixed ASAP. Since we overtook their website, they are aware that the system is broken, but they don't have free money at the moment to spend on a new website/fixing current one. Where we have made a conclusion that fixing it would be harder, therefore more expensive than to move over to our CMS, but money is still money.

**So, how do I escape shell and database commands from this WYSIWYG editor's textarea, that is a single string, but, while preserving UTF-8 encoding of our Latvian alphabet letters - `ā, š, č, ž` etc.?**

Maybe I don't have to escape both, that's why I'm asking.

Thanks in advance!

### Update

#### On Shrapnels' request, an example string (copied from SPAW's HTML view) that would cause Apache to respond with 501:

```
<div>
    <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 128); " class="Apple-style-span">
        <span style="font-size: 12px; " class="Apple-style-span">
            /ls
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

SPAW automatically adds all these dumb elements, and yes, if `/<command>` is inside the string, **501**!

And that's all what it takes to halt, just a namespace referring to a UNIX command line function. Like in this case `/ls`, but could be `/rmdir`, `/mkdir` etc. You could have 20000 symbol stuff there with no `/ls` and it'll work. Once there is something like this - bam, dead!

There was originally a function that was meant to clear all the errors (at least I suppose so, it's original name was - `removeShit();`):

```
$string = $_POST['wysiwyg_textarea']; // SPAW text area

function removeStuff($string){
    return str_replace('/wysiwyg/empty.html', '', $txt);
}
```

The file `/wysiwyg/empty.html` is 0 bytes- completely empty file.

But this doesn't cure the mysql escaping and/or UNIX shell command recognition. Therefore, I need a fix to escape the UNIX commands and any MySQL harmful stuff.

So, I was trying to do it with:

```
return escapeshellcmd(mysqli_real_escape_string($string));
```

But this one strap out all the utf-8 characters, plus, all the new line symbols got converted to simple string "rn" from, I'd guess `\r\n`.

And now I'm looking for a function to escape MySQL and Shell cmd`s in one, because I cannot think of another way how to cure all this mess.

Comment: I think seeing some code would be helpful. I still can't figure out what is going on here. (I have to sign off for today, though)

Comment: @Pekka, I'll update the question with code examples a little bit later. And I hope while I haven't done that, someone will be able to provide a cure or something.

Comment: `when you have a value inside a textarea that refers to a UNIX command, preceded by a / - forward slash symbol and you post it- Apache results in 501 Method Not Implemented.` - elaborate more on this. example would be fine.

Comment: Is "/<command>" causing problems when it appears in HTML output or when submitted in an HTTP request? Regarding the MySQL issues, how much more time would it take to switch to an extension (e.g. mysqli) that supports prepared statements?

Comment: When submitted in an HTTP request. The problem doesn't reside in extension with prepared statements. The thing is, that MySQL works over CLI environment here. I have escaped MySQL- it's working perfectly. But CLI environment somehow gives priority for `/ls`, and tries to execute it even when inside `mysql://` call.

Comment: you'd better ask a question exactly on this topic, free from your assumptions and fantasies. escaping shell commands has nothing to do here. you're getting 501 response from some overcautious software, not PHP code

Comment: Well, because when I escape both, the SQL and Shell- it works, allowing me to post `/ls`, except I lose utf-8 characters in the process. And I never said that there is a problem with PHP code, I said that I have to escape it all in order to get it working. And I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Only thing about PHP here is, that I'm looking for a PHP environment fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither.

Use *either* `escapeshellcmd()` or `mysqli_real_escape_string()`, depending on what you are planning to do with `$string`.

Never use both at the same time. It wouldn't make sense.

Comment: But what if I have to escape both for the same string? Please read - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519802/mysql-cli-web-environment-halts-on-unix and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519717/the-symbols-i-should-be-aware-of-for-sql-injection to understand the situation.

Comment: @Tom I can't say I completely understand your situation :) But: You can't use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` to sanitize a whole query, only the string parts inside it. If you are sending SQL queries through the command line somehow, you need to have applied the escaping function on the string parts beforehand. If you run the escape function on the entire query, you will break it.